# Using phrases from h.264 specifications in code comments

Tags: comments, h.264, specifications, copyright-display

The h.264 specifications from ITU 2017 contain this copyright notice:
(C) ITU 2017
All rights reserved. No part of this publication may be reproduced, by any means whatsoever, without the prior
written permission of ITU.

I am writing a decoder, and I have some structs corresponding to some of the syntax structures defined in these specs. I have been commenting the fields of these structs (which are again reflecting fields of the syntax structures), and I am finding that it's really hard for it not to appear as if I'm just copying from the respective sections in the specs. Some of the phrases are quite short, and there is really no other way to word them.

I've tried looking at the details regarding copyright, and what constitutes an infringement, but I'm still not quite sure if what I'm doing is okay.

If I'm not allowed to do this, what do you guys recommend ?
Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am writing a decoder... I am finding that it's really hard for it not to appear as if I'm just copying from the respective sections in the specs"*

I think you're worried about nothing. When writing a decoder it's logical to quote the  format's official specifications for readability purposes (*eg:* when code is passed on to another coder at some future date).

Are you quoting the **examples pseudo-code** from the **section 7: Syntax and semantics**?

> *"The syntax tables specify a superset of the syntax of all allowed bitstreams. Additional constraints on the syntax may be
>   specified, either directly or indirectly, in other clauses."*
>
> `NOTE – An actual decoder should implement means for identifying entry points into the bitstream and means to identify and handle non-conforming bitstreams. The methods for identifying and handling errors and other such situations are not specified here.`
>
> *"The following table lists examples of pseudo code used to describe the syntax.* *When `syntax_element` appears, it specifies that a `syntax element` is parsed from the bitstream and the bitstream pointer is advanced to the next position beyond the `syntax element` in the bitstream parsing process."*